Highcharts xAxis labels event is giving error after angular upgrade from 7 to 14
we have upgraded  angular 7 to 14 and using highcharts .after upgrade to 14 .highcharts showing build error on below code .its says highcharts  XAxisLabelsOptions does not have events.we have click event on lable of xAxis . below is the code .
xAxis: {
      tickPixelInterval: 20,
      title: {
        text: this._translation.instant('IRM.PAGES.STRATEGY-RESULTS.PORTFOLIO_DETAILS.PERCENTILE'),
        align: 'low',
        offset: 8,
        x: -40,
        y: 25
      },
      labels: {
        style: {
          fontSize: '12px',
          color: '#585858'
        },
        events: {
          click: function () {
            _this.clickEvent(this.chart, this.pos);
            this.chart.redraw();
          }
        },
        useHTML: true,
        formatter: (value) => this.setFormatter(value, _this._selectedColumn),

      },
    },


After upgrading the Highcharts version, you started encountering an error, right? Are you using any custom plugins? Because in the basic Highcharts setup, there's no click event for axis labels. Additionally, it would be great if you could reproduce the issue in an online editor. You can use this demo as a template: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-line?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
